# Images showing different size in different browsers

Tags: php, html, magento, browser

I'm creating a static page in Magento [here](http://www.saeina.com/index.php/product-features). The problem is that images are smaller in Chrome compared to Firefox. My QUESTION is how can I have images in Chrome to have same size as in Firefox. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Javad. Questions here need to be self-contained, so that the statement of the problem can be seen in perpetuity. Your linked example will be fixed in due course, at which point the question will no longer be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the max-width-attribute for this Images.

```
media="all"
    img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    }
```

Comment: Perfect solution ..but how do you get this thought?

Comment: By removing max-width-attribute for img, all images were affected. So what I did was to change the size of the table so table size and image size are now equal and problem is solved. Your solution helped me understand what was causing the problem. Thanks